# More details on startx in Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

From many docs, I read that `startx` is starting LXDE in Raspbian OS. I am a little bit confused.

Will always `startx` run LXDE GUI?

Also I have seen example with using `startlxde`command. How is that command different and why `startx` and `startlxde` are running the same GUI(LXDE)? Or maybe it runs it because it is the default GUI?

How can I choose default GUI if I have multiple ones?

Could you please explain more details around the GUI in Linux systems?

Comment: `startx` is an ASCII script that just checks to make sure the environment and defaults specified in the various directories related to the graphic environment have sane values that are likely to work. You can check. `which startx` -> `/usr/bin/startx`, then `file /usr/bin/startx` -> `/usr/bin/startx: ASCII text`, then you can just go look `vim /usr/bin/startx`. All of the `startfoo` apps (`startlxde`, `startkde`, `startfluxbox`, etc.) are the apps that will launch your specific desktop, usually checking with `startx` in the process.

Answer (score 1):

no, startx does not alway start LXDE. It starts X with the windows manager you specified (actually X is not the same thing than the window manager, but that's an other story).
In your case, startx more or less just call startlxde.
On standard Linux based system (RedHat Ubuntu of else) there is usually a login window that allows to change the window manager you use (usually provided by gdm or kdm)